# Angular 1 - Get the module a controller is running in

Tags: angularjs, filter, module, controller, servicenow

I am working inside a platform where you can create controllers using a web form  and write angular code inside of them... but I do not have access to the parent module.

So here I am in my module, trying to apply a filter but I cannot apply a filter if I do not know the module.

Is there any way I can find out what module I am running in from a controller?

I only have access to this code:

```
    function ($scope, spUtil, snRecordWatcher, $rootScope) {

   }
```

I cannot see the angular.module(blabla)

Thank you,
Alexandru S.

Comment: Hey, I did't get your question can you please elaborate with code what you tried

Comment: I only have access to the controller, I cannot see the angular.module                  The controller I have access to: function ($scope, spUtil, snRecordWatcher, $rootScope) {

   }

Comment: still I did't get your point because if your able to see `angular.module(blabla)` then how can you access angular, but whatever i got it is related to you are not able to access your app, right ? or not then please elaborate some more

Comment: Can you add another injection to that function?

Comment: @Lex - Yeah, like what? :)

Comment: @ojuskulkarni - They allow us to create controllers and code inside of them using an editor from that web platform and we are only able to see the controller function, not the module as well.

Comment: `$rootElement`. Then you can use `$rootElement.attr('ng-app')` to get the name of the module.

Comment: @Lex can you post this as an answer? It worked and I want to mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inject `$rootElement` you can use it to find the name of the module under which the current controller is running. e.g.:

```
function ($scope, spUtil, snRecordWatcher, $rootScope, $rootElement) {
    var module = $rootElement.attr('ng-app');
}
```